# jQuery, how to get elements with data-attribute value that contains "/" and sort them

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am trying to get elements that contains a certain string or value based on their data-attribute and the sort them because they are dates.  I found a nice JSFiddle example that takes the data attribute value and then converts it into a Epoch date format (fine for now), and then sorts them. BUT it only sorts them on a self invoking function page load the first time.  When I wrapped it in a function and tried calling it again, the order switch from ASC to DESC instead of just keeping an ASC or DESC order.
That said, I have a JSFiddle based on the example I found, but now when I try to continually sort the dates and keep an ASC or DESC format, the data value that got convert to Epoch time is getting NaN.

So I tried wrapping it in an IF statement to see IF the data attribute value has a "/" in it but that does not seem to be working right now either.  I have a bunch of comments in my Fiddle I have been working on. I am very close, but it is when I try to click the function to sort each time that I want the order to stay the same without erroring out (check the console you will see the NaN).

This is the Fiddle example using the original code, BUT I wrapped it in a function and call it via a click and the order just reverses every time.  I only want it to go ASC or DESC, not switch back and forth.
http://jsfiddle.net/r8hbx2e3/1/

```js
//ORIGINALLY BASED ON http://jsfiddle.net/greguarr/2fr0vmhu/
//BUT THIS JUST REORDERS EVERYTHING ASC AND DESC ON EVERY CLICK.  JUST WANT IT ONE OR THE OTHER 
//HOW DO YOU GET THIS TO STOP REVERSING ORDER.

//ONE I HAVE BEEN WORKING ON IS HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/ndh9Lyuj/5/

function sortItems() {
  var container = $(".sort-list");
  var items = $(".sort-item");

  items.each(function() {
    // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
    // standardized date format
    var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("/");
    var standardDate = BCDate[0] + " " + BCDate[1] + " " + BCDate[2];
    standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
    $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);
  });

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
    b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
    return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
  }).each(function() {
    container.prepend(this);
  });
};

$('p').on('click', function() {
  sortItems();
});

/* This script sorts your list in descending order... to change it to ascending order change the "less than" operator (<) to "greater than" (>) */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/20/2019">01/20/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="10/15/2017">10/15/2017</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="11/14/2018">11/14/2018</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="02/05/2016">02/05/2016</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="10/31/2013">10/31/2013</li>
</ul>
<p>
  Click me
</p>
```

This is the more extensive Fiddle I have been working on trying to get multiple options to work but keeping the order from switching.  But it doesn't quite work because you will see in the consoles the NaN is coming back each time after the first click through. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ndh9Lyuj/5/

```js
//ORIGINALLY BASED ON http://jsfiddle.net/greguarr/2fr0vmhu/

var container = $(".sort-list");
var items = $(".sort-item");
var yourArray = [];

function me() {
  items.each(function() {
    console.log("up top" + $(this).attr("data-event-date"));
    // Convert the string in 'data-event-date' attribute to a more
    // standardized date format

    if ($(this).attr("data-event-date").indexOf("/")) { //This does not seem to be working to check if data attribute has value with a slash. 
      var BCDate = $(this).attr("data-event-date").split("/");
      var standardDate = BCDate[0] + " " + BCDate[1] + " " + BCDate[2];
      standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
      $(this).attr("data-event-date", standardDate);
      console.log("with standard date " + $(this).attr("data-event-date"));
    }
    console.log($(this).attr("data-event-date"));
    // yourArray.push($(this).prop('data-event-date').split(' ')[0]);
  });

  //    nowSort(items);
  //    }
  //function nowSort(items){
  items.sort(function(a, b) {
      a = parseFloat($(a).attr("data-event-date"));
      b = parseFloat($(b).attr("data-event-date"));
      // if(a < b){
      // return -1
      //}
      // return 0;
      // a = $(a).attr("data-event-date");
      // b = $(b).attr("data-event-date");
      return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
      // return a > b;
      //alert('sort');
    })
    .each(function() {
      container.prepend(this);
    });
  //alert('sort');
}

$('p').on('click', function() {
  me();
});

/* This script sorts your list in descending order... to change it to ascending order change the "less than" operator (<) to "greater than" (>) */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="04/20/2019">04/20/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="03/05/2017">03/05/2017</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="04/18/2019">04/18/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/20/2016">01/20/2016</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="10/31/2019">10/31/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="02/30/2019">02/31/2019</li>
</ul>
<p>
  click me
</p>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Added embedded code snippets. My apologies for not including the whole thing the first time.

Comment: Small side note while evaluating the scripts; `return a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;` can be just `return b - a;`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks that is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Changed the method to pass in `asc` or `desc`
- Only convert the date once, and convert it to ISO format
- Do not override the original data field
- When sorting, check if the value is `asc` or not to determine which way to sort

```js
$('p').on('click', function(){ sortItems('desc'); });

function sortItems (sortDirection) {
  var container = $(".sort-list");
  var items = $(".sort-item");

  items.filter(function(){
    return !$(this).data('convertedEventDate');
  }).each(function() {
    var BCDate = $(this).data("eventDate").split("/");
    var standardDate = `${BCDate[2]}-${BCDate[0]}-${BCDate[1]}`;
    
    standardDate = new Date(standardDate).getTime();
    $(this).data("convertedEventDate", standardDate);
  });
  
  container.append(
    items.sort(function(a, b){
      var $aTime = $(a).data('convertedEventDate');
      var $bTime = $(b).data('convertedEventDate');
      
      if (sortDirection === 'asc') {
        return $aTime - $bTime;
      } else {
        return $bTime - $aTime;
      }
    })
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort-list">
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="01/20/2019">01/20/2019</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="10/15/2017">10/15/2017</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="11/14/2018">11/14/2018</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="02/05/2016">02/05/2016</li>
  <li class="sort-item" data-event-date="10/31/2013">10/31/2013</li>
</ul>

<p>Click me</p>
```

Comment: that works perfectly!  One question, and this is just for own understanding, In the HTML the data attribute is 'data-event-date' but in the JS it is 
       var BCDate = $(this).data("eventDate").split("/");  But it still works, can you explain a bit of why?

Comment: The camel case key you give to `data()` is converted to have the dashes in it, based on the placement of the camel case.  And `data()` specifically works with data-* attributes, so it takes care of the prefix and you leave it off.  @ClosDesign

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that.  Thank you!